# If points cannot be added, then how can we define $\lim_{m \to \infty}(a_m+b_m)$ where $a_m$ and $b_m$ are sequences of points in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am following Hubbard's multivariable calculus book. In the beginning of the book, it says that points cannot be added but vectors can.

> As a rule, it doesn't make sense to add points together, any more than it makes sense to add positions "Boston" and "New York"...

But later in the sequences of points, we define $\lim_{m \to \infty}(a_m+b_m)$. If it doesn't make sense, how can we add points $a_m$ and $b_m$?

As a similar question I would like to ask how to multiply a point in $\mathbb R^n$ with a number. The book doesn't say anything about it but $\lim_{m \to \infty}(c_m a_m)$ is also defined where $c_m$ is a sequence of numbers. Is

$$c\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1  \\
        x_2  \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
        cx_1  \\
        cx_2  \\
        cx_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}\text{?}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense to add two points from a *vector space*. It doesn't really make sense to add two points from an affine space. That is, you need to impose a system of coordinates before it makes sense to add them. (If you remove some of the structure from a vector space, you get an affine space.)

Originally, the author was probably talking about $\mathbb{R}^n$ the affine space. However, when it comes to operations, we move to the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$, where it does make sense to add points coordinatewise. The reason it now makes sense is because there is this privileged "zero" point and these privileged "basis" points of the form $(1, 0, \dots, 0), (0, 1, 0, \dots, 0), \dots$ which together are what distinguish the position of all other points.

We multiply points by a real number coordinatewise also. Think of it as applying the matrix transformation $c I$, if you're happier with performing linear maps on vectors.

Comment: There is not a single clue about affine spaces in the book. Also, during the linear algebra course, there was no distinction between a point and a vector in a vector space $\mathbb R^n$. So I am confused and I can't comprehend how vectors and points coexist in a vector space. Do you mean coordinates of vectors are points? What happens if we change the basis then?

Comment: They probably didn't mention "affine space" explicitly, but they meant it. OK, a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is represented by a vector $v$. One is just a way of representing the other, just as $2$ (analogous to a vector) is a way of representing a certain natural number (analogous to a point). The reason it makes sense to say "2" is because we have a 0 to compare with: that's what lets us say that 2+3 = 5, because both 2 and 3 have definite distances from our privileged 0 and we have this rule that lets us add distances.

Comment: Coordinates of vectors are not points. If we impose a basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we may obtain coordinates for any vector. Then changing the basis changes the coordinates we obtain, because we're "looking at $\mathbb{R}^n$ in a different light". The underlying point remains the same. There is no "underlying vector" - the vector is a property of the point together with a basis, which allows us to extract coordinates.

Comment: A basis is an eyepiece you may look through so as to regard $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a collection of vectors. Without the eyepiece, it's just points, but if you look through the eyepiece you see this structure that allows you to say "this point corresponds to the vector $v$ which has coordinates $(v_1, \dots, v_n)$". If you change the eyepiece, the correspondence may change, and the coordinates may change. The underlying point is "the same".

Comment: Thank you for your explanations I almost clarified things in my mind. But you mention "the underlying point is the same". You mean in the answer that the coordinates of this point is the coordinates of the standard basis vectors $\vec e_1, \vec e_2, ...$ right?

Comment: A point doesn't have coordinates at all, in the absence of some larger structure - that's what the Boston example in the book was about. I could point to Boston if we were flying on a plane, but I couldn't tell you its coordinates (because it doesn't have any), *unless* I know that we have latitude and longitude. Lat/long provides us with a coordinate system on the sphere, much like the standard basis does in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and if I know that we have lat/long, I can give you the coordinates of Boston. Similarly, if I know you're using the standard basis, I can give you coordinates of a point.

Comment: Sometimes self study can be a pain without an instructor against a book  which doesn't explain such things clearly. Thank you for being an instructor to me and for your patience.